# Overflow em unsigned long int - C

Tags: c

O tipo unsigned long int armazena um valor máximo de 4294967295 (2^32 - 1) enquanto que o valor float armazena um máximo de 10^38.

Estou fazendo um teste de overflow numa variável unsigned long int. Olhem o código abaixo, por favor.

A função abaixo é uma função recursiva que calcula o número de passos que um dado número l
eva para convergir para 1 de acordo com a conjectura de Collatz.
Basicamente eu quero testar é

```
#define max 4294967295

unsigned long int collatz(unsigned long int n, unsigned long int passos, unsigned long int *maiorN) {
    float overflow = 3 * n + 1;
    if (overflow > max)
        return -1;

    if (n == 1)
        return passos;
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
        return collatz(n / 2, passos + 1, maiorN);
    else { 
        if ((3 * n + 1) > *maiorN)
            *maiorN = 3 * n + 1;
        return collatz(3 * n + 1, passos + 1, maiorN);
    }    
}
```

Aparentemente esse código está correto, pelo menos do meu ponto de vista, mas parece que dá overflow antes do esperado.

Alguém poderia dar uma olhada, por favor?

Comment: olhando superficialmente, acho que onde está "float overflow = 3 * n + 1;" deveria ser "float overflow = 3.0 * n + 1;" para evitar um possível overflow nas operações " 3 * n + 1", que são feitas em inteiro.